# Proc SQL where calculated value starts with

Tags: sas

I'm writing a `proc sql` statement where I'd like to subset to entries where some value starts with `'3'` or `'1'` while mapping to character (I'm concatenating a number of data sets, some of which have numeric codings and some of which use character codings.) The data are loaded from `sas7bdat` files referenced via a `libname` statement.

I think I know how to do each of these separately in the SQL where string,  but I don't know how to do them together:

```
where VALUE like '3%'
where VALUE in ('3', '1')
where VALUE in (3, 1)
```

But I'm not sure how to make it such that I am mapping to a character dtype and then checking both boxes of starting with `'3'` or `'1'`. I believe there is some way to calculate a value in the call but I don't know how to convert to character.

Where `VALUE` is a string, it is two characters long. Where it is an integer, that number never has more than two digits and values range from 1 to 99.

Comment: Can't you just fix the reason the source datasets are defining the variable as different types before trying to use them?  For example are you using PROC IMPORT to create the datasets from text files instead of writing your own data step code?

Comment: Oh, the data sets are already present as `sas7bdat` files, I'm referencing them via a `libname` step

Comment: So are the values valid integers, even when they are character string?  Are they less than 16 digits long?  If not then your numeric variables might have already lost key information.  Are they always the same number of digits?  Do you only want to select based on the first digit (most significant digit if a number)?

Comment: They are valid integers when they are numeric; I just want to select on the first character in ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a [colon operator](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/056-2009.pdf)?

```
where VALUE in: (3, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PUT() , or PUTN(), function to convert numbers to string.  You either use the -L modifier on the format or just the LEFT() or STRIP() function to remove leading spaces from the result.

```
   create table want as 
     select * from (

   select put(num_id,10.-L) as id 
        , ....
   from ds1
   union 
   select char_id as id
        , ...
   from ds2
     
     )
     where char(id,1) in ('1','3')
   ;
```

Comment: If I had this in a macro, is there a way that would accept both character and integer inputs that map them to character?

Comment: Sure.  First step is to know the variable type so the macro can generate the appropriate code based on the type. So either have the macro accept that information as input or have it figure it out.   For example here is a utility macro you could use to test the type of a variable in a dataset. https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/varexist.sas